# ios App Store show support for wallet even though Wallet has been disabled in app capabilities

Tags: ios, wallet

Our app has not been integrated with wallet and it is also disabled in within capabilities from xcode. The only framework we are importing is AirshipKit (UrbanAirship) for push notifications. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was working with the Urban Airship support team regarding this issue. They responded with an update stating that in their latest release v7.2.0 they removed support for Wallet all together which should resolve the issue.

https://bintray.com/urbanairship/iOS/urbanairship-sdk/7.2.0/view.